# JavaScript - wait function to execute completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 JS functions:

`check_fields()` and `send_form()` .

`send_form()` function should call `check_fields()` function:

```
function check_fields()
{
   //do an ajax request causing a little delay
   //return true in case of valid fields or false in case of error(s)
}

function send_form()
{
if ( !check_fields() )
            return;
//do stuff here
}
```

The problem is that send_form() function doesn't execute quickly, so I have to know when it had executed completely. 
How could I know that?

PS: If I remove the ajax request, everything works fine.

Comment: read up on using `callbacks` or `promises` - plenty of questions on both here at SO

Comment: Have a look at jquery's when ... done http://stackoverflow.com/a/9865124/2375207